# numpy.ndarray.size doesn't work on numpy array?

Tags: numpy-ndarray

Just trying to extract the length of a numpy (1D) array. Wondering why this doesn't work.

```
print(np.ndarray.size(np.array([1,2,2])))
```

I expected to get 3. Instead I get TypeError: 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Size is a property and not a method.  Try using the built-in ‘len’ function instead

```
print(len(np.array([1,2,3])))
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does the f' notation mean? Looks like I can run without it.

Comment: You can, the f’ notation is an f-string in Python, allows for inserting evaluations into fixed strings.  I used it by habit, it isn’t necessary here as the len function returns an int which can be printed directly.   I’ll edit for clarity